# DataSnapshot' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to import in visual studio code, but it giving this error `import { DataSnapshot } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/database';` `DataSnapshot' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`

[image]

here is full code of my index.ts, there is red line under datasnapshot and in error object

```
exports.sendNotificationOnAssignmentCreated = functions.database.ref('/VoltaCoin/Notifications/{user_id}').onCreate((data, context) =>{

const id = context.params.id;
const eventId = context.eventId;
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
console.log('here is fid 22 ', user_id);


const payload = {
    notification:{
        title : "You are now assigned",
        body : "New Assignment",
        icon : "default",
        sound : "default"
    }
};


var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/IWFM/Assignments/Olnaj/AFSM/"+user_id+'/assignTo');

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var assignTo = snapshot.val();

    var refstaf = db.ref("/IWFM/Stafs/Olnaj/1234/"+assignTo+'/FID');
    refstaf.on("value", function(snapshot1){
        var FID = snapshot1.val();
        console.log('here is ' + FID);
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(FID, payload).then(response=>{
            // console.log('this was the notification feature');
        });
    }, function(errorObject)
    {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });


}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

please if anyone can help me to fix

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the entire import line if you're not using the symbol it references.